# How do I add Metasploit into my PATH variable?

Tags: bash, command-line, path

I have Metasploit installed on my Mac in `/usr/local/share/msf`.
Everytime I want to use it I have to cd into that directory and use `msfconsole`.

If I try to `/usr/local/share/msf/msfconsole` in my home directory I get an error that gems are missing and I should `bundle install` but if I cd to `msf` and run `msfconsole` it runs with no problems although I have to use `sudo -E msfconsole` to utilise it fully.

Does anyone know how to add `/usr/local/share/msf` as an environment called `$MSF` that I can run its commands as root (`sudo -E`) and use its dependencies/gems?

I have the same problem for BeEF too but thats a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I believe you should add this to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/usr/local/share/msf/config/database.yml
```

*(edit the path accordingly)*

Comment: Thats the config, which is different and is already done. I installed according to this: http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-framewor/ Scroll down to Create Symlink For Regular Use, this was the only part of the tut that never worked.

Comment: @Anonymous Did you use `brew`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link somewhere in your path.

```
 ln -s /usr/local/share/msf/msfconsole /usr/local/bin/msfconsole
```

You will probably need to do that for things like msfupdate etc.
As for the gems, cd to the directory metasploit is in and

```
bundle install
```

If you want to add an environment variable then add this to .bashrc, or whatever shell you are using.

```
export MSF=/usr/local/share/msf
```

However that doesn't really 'fix' your problem, the first does.